# CodeIgniter set error message with value in message

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

So I read the [user guide for form validation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors) and there it shows how to set custom message. For example, if I put this in my code

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', '%s address already registered.');
```

it will output `E-mail address already registered.` (If it is validation for email field)

What I want to do is have a message that will say `E-mail address test@website.com already registered.` Is there a code to put to show the value of the field that is being passed? (like %s, that shows the field name)

Comment: are you getting the email address from post?

Comment: It is a form, with validation taking place from controller and calling functions accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', '%s address ' . $this->input->post('email', true) . ' already registered.');
```

Out of the box, it only translates the field *name* with `sprintf`, not the field *value*:

```
$message = sprintf($line, $this->_translate_fieldname($row['label']), $param);
```

Simply extend `CI_Form_validation` with `MY_Form_validation` and parse the string to fit your needs.

Comment: This will work, however, is there a way to do it something similar to %s? For example instead of `$this->input->post('email');` put `%v`?